# file_get_contents and cURL return totally different content in same script

Tags: php, curl, soap, soap-client

I'm debugging a not working SOAP client, which does not work because somehow the client cannot resolve the WSDL locally. To debug this I created the following script.

The curl call has the right response, the file_get_contents has a totally different response. At first I thought this was a DNS issue, but the curl call should also return the wrong response in that case.

Any idea what might be the root cause?

```
<?php
function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
var_dump(get_data("http://example.com")); // right response
var_dump(file_get_contents("http://example.com"); // wrong response
```

Comment: I think this will be hard to answer if you can't define what "totally different" in this case is, and some examples would be useful.

Comment: The curl variant is equal to the browser output for the requested URL. The file_get_contents call returns a page with 'This domain has been reserved'

Comment: Just to confirm, the URLs you're using are _exactly_ the same, you can do a comparison on them and get true etc etc. If so.... I have no idea...

Comment: Yeah, checked with ===

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the issue was resolved after a restart of Apache. Still uncertain what the problem was. It certainly wasn't DNS TTL (waited 48 hours).